# How to make sure you have overriden (hide) a method in a derived class in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
class Base {

    public:
         void foo() const {
             std::cout << "foo const" << std::endl;
         }

};


class Derived : public Base {

  public:
         void foo()  {
             std::cout << "foo"<< std::endl;
         }


 }
```

I want to make sure that foo() const is correctly hidden for Base.  Yeah, this is a bad idea, and maybe I should make Base::foo() const a pure virtual to require Dervied::foo() to overridde correctly — but let's say that I cannot make Base::foo() const pure virtual.  Is there a better way to make sure Base::foo() const is correctly hidden in Derived?

Edit: I want to make sure that in Derived I have correctly hidden the base implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly hidden" ? Either a function is overridden, or it is hidden. Can't be both.

Comment: Are you asking if there is some way to get the same behaviour as the c# override keyword?  This excellent keyword ensures that the function is actually overriding something.  It's an easy mistake to not override something in c++ when you meant to because of a difference in function signature.

Comment: By "hidden" do you mean not public?

Comment: Correctly hidden refers to I am actually hiding the foo implementation of Base in Derived. In the implementation above I don't actually hide the implementation since I have missed the cost.

Comment: That's then called "override". You do hide it in any case if it is not virtual and has the same name. If it *is* virtual and you get the signatures right, then you override it, which means you don't hide it.

Answer (score 4):

Simply by defining a member function foo in the derived class, you have hidden all of the foo functions in the base class.

You'll need to refine the question a little - are you concerned that the foo in the derived class is not a proper replacement for the foo in the base class? I'm having a hard time trying to determine what you're really asking for.

**Edit:** Based on your edit and additional comments, I think you have a misunderstanding of how hiding works in C++. In this case, it doesn't matter that one function is const and the other one isn't - once C++ finds a function foo in the derived class, it stops looking anywhere else! This is usually a huge trap for people. Consider the following:

```
class Base
{
    void foo(double d)
    {
        cout << d;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
    void foo(int i)
    {
        cout << i;
    }
};

Derived obj;
obj.foo(123.456);
```

What do you think the output is?  It's 123! And you probably got a compiler warning telling you the double value was going to be truncated. Even though the function signature that takes a double is obviously a better match, it's never considered - it has been hidden.

Answer (score 1):

"void foo() const" and "void foo()" are two completely different functions as far as C++ is concerned.  That's why you don't see the Derived's "foo" hiding the "foo" from the Base.

Comment: That's not true, if a base class defines a function then it hides all functions with the same name in the base class even if they have different parameters (don't believe me? try it), the way to make these functions visible again is to use "using base::foo;"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to HIDE foo() from Base? If you want to exploit polymorphism you need to make the base version of foo() virtual. It does not have to be pure, though. Otherwise you get static binding - do you want that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make it pure virtual and thereby force the implementation, you might just make the body of `foo()` in the `Base` class just immediately throw an exception.  This serves the purpose of forcing any implementors and users to implement an override, or have it blow up when they try to use it.

I've seen this done before, and while it's a bit ugly, it very certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly, you are asking how to make sure that `Derived` classes override the method compulsorily, without making the method pure in `Base` class.

By making sure all of your derived classes to provide the implementation of the method, IMHO you are  hinting that the method in `Base` class is really not used for any purpose. The objects must invoke any of the `Derived` class version of the method `foo()`. Hence, the method should be made pure virtual in my opinion. I don't think any other way to achieve this, I believe.

Also, note that in your example you have changed the signature of `foo()` in `Base` and `Derived`. This makes the `Base` class method to be invisible in `Derived` class. Unless you use `using Base::foo`, the method `foo()` will not be visible to `Derived` class.

Answer (score 0):

In Base::foo(), you could do the following:

```
assert (dynamic_cast<const Derived*> (this) == NULL);
```

But it has three problems:

1. It requires a change in the Base class, which should be closed to modification.
2. It may be stronger than you need, since you may want to permit Base::foo() to be called from a Base object or explicitly.
3. It uses RTTI, which means a vtbl, which might be why you didn't want to user virtual functions to begin with.